# embedded white space in nagios arguments

Tags: nagios

I created my own nagios command

```
$USER1$/check_http -H $HOSTNAME$ -p $ARG1$ -u $ARG2$ -e $ARG3$ -w 5 -c 10 -4
```

used by a new service.

When the `$ARG3$` contains some white space (for instance "200 OK") the service fail reporting "name or service not known". As in the following command line:

```
check_http -H 1.1.1.1 -u /xxx/1234.pdf -w 5 -c 10 -e 200 OK   
Name or service not known
```

How can I quote the white space in some way?

Comment: Try to quote your args with " for example -e "200 OK"

Comment: Hi deagh. The double quoting worked fine from the command line of the nagios server (i.e, from the bash shell) but I tried to use the double quotes in the value of $ARG3$ or escaping the space character in the value of $ARG3$ IN THE SERVICE DEFINITION. They didn't work. Finally MadHatter show me the clue in his answer: double quoting the $ARG3$ in the command definition ($USER1$/check_http -H $HOSTNAME$ -p $ARG1$ -u $ARG2$ -e "$ARG3$" -w 5 -c 10 -4). Thanx anyway for your interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the command line, just quote it

```
[me@nagios ~]$ /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_http -H www.teaparty.net -u http://www.teaparty.net/index.html -w 5 -c 10 -e "200 OK"  
HTTP OK: Status line output matched "200 OK" - 10522 bytes in 0.029 second response time |time=0.029431s;5.000000;10.000000;0.000000 size=10522B;;;0
```

In the NAGIOS config file, merely separating it from `$ARG2$` with a `!` should be enough to protect it; in my experience, NAGIOS will generally protect spaces.  If that doesn't work, quote it in `$ARG3$` also.

Comment: Why not using just the numeric code? I've always used this approach and it works!

Comment: So have I, and so it does.  I assume the OP has some business reason for wanting to do it his/her way, and it doesn't seem to hurt anything to do it.

Comment: Thanx MadHatter. Simply double-quoting $ARG3$ in the command definition

Comment: Glad you got an answer that worked for you.  I notice this is your first question, so may I mention that local etiquette is that when you're happy with an answer to your question, you accept it by clicking the tick outline next to it?  This drives the SF reputation system for both you and the author of the answer.  My apologies if you already knew that.